# Turn Positive into negative?

Tags: java

I've got this code

```
public class FiboNegativV {
    int negativ(int nv) {
        if (nv ==0)
        return 1;

        if (nv ==1)
        return 2;

        return negativ(nv-1) + negativ(nv-2); 
   }
}
```

Now I would like to turn the final number into negative. I've tried a few things like "nv = -nv;" But I usually got stackover when I put it before the 
"return negativ(nv-1) + negativ(nv-2)" and it is unreachable when it's after this line.

Comment: If the `x` is unnecessary, why is it in your question?

Comment: of course every statement after the return statement is unreachable, what else did you expect?

Comment: Your problem isn't negating a number but it seems you get a `StackOverflowError` due to massive (and probably unnecessary) recursion. What numbers are you starting with? And did you debug your code?

Comment: you can apply simple condition `number = (number > 0) ? number * -1 : number`

Comment: @Florian Nolte maybe you should give an example of the sequence you want, should it be `-1, -1, -2, -3, -5, -8, ...` ? What about negative input?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need function for that just do it like this:

```
int x *= -1;
```

Comment: this doesn't compile, `int x = VALUE;` should be declared before `x *= -1;`

Comment: also negating a negative number yields a positive one, and OP wanted "turn the final number into negative"

Answer (score 0):

> If you only want to convert positive into negative then

`nv = (nv > 0) ? nv * -1 : nv`

> if you want to convert positive to negative and negative to positive then

```
nv = nv * -1
```

Below your code will look like

```
public class FiboNegativ
 {

    public FiboNegativV(){}

      int negativ(int nv)
      {
         return (nv > 0) ? nv*-1 : nv; 
      }
}
```

Comment: yeah but where shut I write down the line?

Comment: you totally changed the functionality of OP's method, disregarding the Fibbonacci sequence

Comment: @Hawk yes but Florian made his functions in such way i just tried to minimise his code!!

Comment: @BinitGhetiya firstly you included totally redundant x field and constructor; secondly you have rewritten his method **totally**, not even leaving a comment there indicating that anything else should be in the method - this is totally misleading

Comment: @Hawk bro x thing is not my coding its questioners defined value ! in above comment you can see that he asked me where to make change in code `yeah but where shut I write down the line?` so i copy pasted his code and make related change so that his code will work.. and i can see that he's very beginner user and developer in java.

Comment: @BinitGhetiya that is what I am talking about, he wanted to know the exact line where to put the piece of code you provided and you have rewritten his method totally. In the current state your code is not what it is meant to be, please update your answer and provide the full code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164341/discussion-between-binit-ghetiya-and-hawk).

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers for some reason disregard your initial intention of a Fibbonacci sequence. But I do not understand why they do not keep the context. Your method obviously tries to do a Fibbonacci sequence with recursion yielding negative numbers.

---

> Now I would like to turn the final number into negative.

The simplest and most intuitive way of negatinv a number is to use a **unary minus operator** = just add a minus before the expression (so negating `x` to `-x`). We use this only on positive numbers, so that the negative ones stay negative: *(note: this is a ternary operator)*

```
(result > 0) ? -result : result;
```

However the **big mistake** is that you do NOT handle negative numbers in the recursive method in the first place! Of course you run into stack overflow, because the recursive negative numbers are going to get lower and lower.

```
static int negativFib(int nv)
{
    //turn negative input into positive
    nv = nv < 0 ? -nv : nv;
    //base cases
    if (nv == 0)
        return 1;
    if (nv == 1)
        return 2;

    final int result = negativFib(nv - 1) + negativFib(nv - 2);
    //turn the number into negative
    return result > 0 ? -result : result;
}
```

---

### Alternative algorithm

An another problem which could occur is that with big numbers, the recursion comes to a stack overflow. You could prevent this by using some other algorithm, f.e. [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). With dynamic programming Fibbonacci sequence you store the previous 2 results every time and solve the problem in iterations, instead of recursion.

Comment: The OP doesn't make it clear that they're writing a Fibonacci generator other than the class name. The question title is "Turn positive number into negative number". Our answers all answer that question.

Comment: @MarkYisri "Now I would like to turn the **final** number into negative." he wanted only to change the result, not the whole method, yet you have rewriten it totally

Comment: The only part of the question that even remotely mentions Fibonacci is the class name. You can't extrapolate one word and produce a different question.

Comment: @MarkYisri I disagree, his implementation is a clear attempt at recursive Fib. seq. Probably a bit odd one, because usually it goes like `1,1,2,3, ...` but he implemented it with input starting at 0 and going up: `1,2,3, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want only the final number to be negative, the easiest way is to work with absolute numbers, and return negative numbers, as per the following:

```
public class FiboNegativV {
    int negativ(int nv) {
        return (nv == 0) ? -1 :
            (nv == 1) ? -2 : 
            -(Math.abs(negativ(nv-1)) + Math.abs(negativ(nv-2))); 
   }
}
```

The assumption I have made, above, is that the initial input to the function will always be positive. Your original code confirms this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
-1 * (Math.abs(negativ(nv-1) + negativ(nv-2)));
```

**Thus the result will be negative regardless of the values given.**